# Doing text overlay on video

Tags: video, editing

What's the easiest (preferably free) tool to do a text overlay akin to the one shown in this Strava ad video.

https://youtu.be/4BV30EDMmn4

Comment: Welcome travelverse :) You've earned negative reputation, because your question shows no effort. In order to **get a solid answer** (and positive reputation of course), please edit your question by adding more information and context. Also might be a good idea starting with the tour to get your first badge: http://video.stackexchange.com/tour.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do with any basic video editor.

Checkout lightworks if you are in windows or openshot if you are in Linux